# Swift inherence task

Tags: mvvm, swift2, adapter

Some days ago I moved to swift coding after objc. And when I writing adapter with MVVM pattern, I confused with next case, which could be done in objc without any problems.

So in Objc: We have IDTableViewController with presenter (viewModel) property

```
@interface IDTableViewController : UITableViewController
    @property (nonatomic, strong) id<IDCollectionPresenterProtocol> presenter;
@end
```

And when we inherit IDTableViewController, we override class of presenter in extension (which of course conforms to protocol mentioned above)

```
UsersViewController.h 
@interface UsersViewController : IDTableViewController

UsersViewController.m 
@interface UsersViewController ()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UsersPresenter *presenter;
@end

@implementation UsersViewController
@dynamic presenter;
```

And all is fine... But in swift I can't do the same thing. I can't override class of property in UsersViewController

```
class IDTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var viewModel : IDCollectionPresenterProtocol?
}
class UsersViewController: IDTableViewController {

    var viewModel : UsersPresenter?
}
```

Can I do this? And How I could implement it, if it's not legal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches:

1. You can override stored property with computed property that is a front-end to your own private stored property e.g.:

   ```
   class UsersViewController: IDTableViewController {
       private var usersViewModel: UsersPresenter?
       override var viewModel: IDCollectionPresenterProtocol? {
           get { return usersViewModel }
           set { usersViewModel = newValue as! UsersPresenter }
       }
   }
   ```
2. You could not override `viewModel` at all, and just implement `usersViewModel` as a computed property itself if you need a `UsersPresenter` interface to the view model within `UsersViewController`:

   ```
   class UsersViewController: IDTableViewController {
       private var usersViewModel: UsersPresenter? {
           get { return viewModel as? UsersPresenter }
           set { viewModel = newValue }
       }
   }
   ```

The other, more naturally Swifty ways of dealing with this (e.g. generics or protocol with default implementations of the `UITableViewDataSource` methods in a protocol extension) don't play well with Objective-C, so you'll have problems when using them as view controllers or as a `UITableViewDataSource`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, computed private property is what i need. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be what you want:

```
protocol MyProtocol {

}

class ImplementedProtocol : MyProtocol {

}

class MyBaseClass<T : MyProtocol> {
    var viewModel : T?
}

class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass<ImplementedProtocol> {

}
```

Now, when you instantiate `MyDerivedClass`, `viewModel` will be of type `ImplementedProtocol`.
A word of warning: Xcode 7.3 didn't correctly infer the type of `viewModel` in the autocompletion, but assigning it to a variable fixed that - so it's just an Xcode bug that will hopefully be fixed very soon.

Comment: If we lived in a purely Swift world, I agree that this is good way to do it. The problem is that generics can't be represented in Objective-C, and thus attempts to use generics for a view controller and/or `UITableViewDataSource` will not work.

Comment: Ah yes, interop with objective-c is a problem of course. It's one of the pains we have to live with at the moment :(